Compilation error when using C++ template functions that accept as arguments another functions that accept references to pointers
Here is the most basic example of the C++ code that raises this compilation error:
template <typename T>
void TestF(int(*func)(const T&)) {

}

int IntNormal(const int& x) {
    return x;
}

int IntPointer(const int*& x) {
    return *x;
}

int main() {
    TestF<int>(IntNormal); //Works just fine
    TestF<int*>(IntPointer); //Gives compilation error
    return 0;
};

The error Intellisense gives me is :
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "TestF" matches the argument list

Error   C2664   'void TestF<const int*>(int (__cdecl *)(const T &))': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(const int *&)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(const T &)'
        with
        [
            T=const int *
        ]

I just don't understand why it works just fine with normal int but it doesn't with int*, even though it looks as if I was using correct method signature.

A pointer to a const int is not the same as a const pointer to an int.  When T is int*, const T makes the pointer const.

Could you explain better? I'm quite new to c++ so I may not understand some small details

I am looking for the way to use templates with const references, sometimes they may be references to actual objects and sometimes pointers - how would you fix my code so there is no compilation error?

What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?

Thank you for the link, looks very useful. It will take time for me to understand all this :D For now just wondering how to make a working code in this case

Working in what way? It's easy to make code that compiles but does something different from the desired result. We don't know the desired result, so the best we can do is guess at what you really want. This is the problem with the answer below. It compiles, but does it do what you need it to do? Only you can answer that, and once you do, please update the question to make the connection between the question and the answer clear to future askers.

@user4581301 I have updated my question to show what i wanted to achieve.

You say "I need a template that works with pointer", but in your answer below you do not actually tweak the template, but you tweak the argument that is passed to the function template instance. So, what is it really that you need?

as I wrote- want to work with both pointers and normal objects. I want to learn how to specify both - template and methods so I can pass them into template function. in this case the issue was with my wrong understanding of const. So modifying the method is closer to what I wanted to achieve.

I'm glad that I managed to learn something new

The day you stop learning is the day you die.

@user4581301 Well said!

Yes :) It works fine now. But I need to wait few days before accepting my own answer

At first I wanted to thank Drew Dormann for his link:
What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int * const?
I have read this and managed to write working code:
template <typename T>
void TestF(int(*func)(const T&)) {

}


int IntNormal(const int& x) {
    return x;
}

int IntPointer(int*const& x) {  //Here is fix - I write int * const & instead of const int * &
    return *x;
}

int main() {
    TestF<int>(IntNormal); //Works just fine
    TestF<int*>(IntPointer);  //Now works after above fix
    return 0;
};


you realize that those 2 functions work on two different things, one works on a const int, the other works on const pointer to non-const int, the const-ness of the int is not preserved.

I'm starting getting headache ^^ of all the const and non-const :D

... which means that IntPointer is free to modify the int that x is pointing at. It just promises to not make x point anywhere else.

I don't mind that in my case. I just want the pointer to be const

Ok, in that case you nailed it :-)
